# How to call a check for a product class in Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

In the Ubercart D7 uc attribute module I am trying to  run code on the fieldset attribute if the product is a specific product class in the module with an if statement.

This calls an  if  for payment received

```
      if ($op == 'update' && $order->order_status == 'payment_received' && $arg2 == 'completed') { 
// ... your code goes here
```

}

How do I call it for a product class??

In uc_attributes module at

```
   function uc_attribute_uc_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //. other code of module's function... 
    $element[$key]['#type'] = 'fieldset';
    //    if (product class . ..) {
  // ... your code goes here
```

So that only the validate code runs on the field set if the product is the same product class

I have rest of the code largely ready to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **node type** is Ubercart class. Because, then you create a new class in `/admin/store/products/classes` it will create the new content type in `/admin/structure/types`
So code will like next:

```
if ($op == 'update' && $order->order_status == 'payment_received' && $arg2 == 'completed') {
  if (is_array($order->products)) {
    foreach ($order->products as $product) {
      if ($product->type == 'SOMECLASS') {
         // DO something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Nikit, Thanks this is what I was after.  Someone downvoted this so I upvoted back to zero.  My question was not clear - I am calling this inside the uc_attributes module at the function uc_attribute_uc_form_alter - so I am guessing I do not need the foreach loop.  I am trying to operate on the fieldset textfield to regulate and validate what can be entered there, using ajax and callback throwing form errors for this class of product before allowing the product to be added to the cart.  I am working on it - it will be tricky to get to work because I do not think I can nest functions

Comment: @wilburunion catch my vote up :)
About ajax - I assume it should be another question or search here for answers.

Answer (score 0):

The function to use is:

```
uc_product_is_product($node)
```

This returns a boolean variable indicating whether the node is a product type.

Comment: Not trying to test - I know the class - it already exists, I think Nikit answered what I needed

Comment: If you're just trying to check to see if a node is of a specific known type, then that's not even an Ubercart question.

Comment: Nikit answered it.  I wanted the syntax to call a specific product class in the if statement in a module

Comment: Yes, I understand, but that is NEVER necessary if all you want to do is add validation for a textfield attribute for a specific product class in Ubercart. You asked the wrong question, and you are heading down the wrong path.

Comment: OK - so how do you propose it must be done since JQuery, Ajax and php code functions must be done on the text field as characters are typed and then error out preventing an add to cart if the field is not valid??